# TouchListView in Fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm using TouchListView in my app. After converting all activities to fragments I've a question: the fragment with touchlistview inside is 50% of my tablet screen. If I drag a row the dragged row is exactly in the middle of the screen. But this distorts the other fragment. What can I do to prevent overlaying a different fragment?

Thanks in advance
Thomas

Comment: If by `TouchListView` you mean https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist bear in mind that it is no longer supported. I have never tried using it in a fragment, let alone one alongside some other fragment. The code, derived from an old edition of the AOSP Music app, pretty much assumed that the whole screen was a `ListView`.

Comment: So it's good for you to hear that it works. The only issue I discovered is the one I mentioned above ;-) I need a sortable list and yours is the only one I found :-)

Comment: Well, it doesn't work, as is evidenced by your problem. The drag logic involves putting a "row" in a floating window-y thing above the `ListView`, and the drag logic isn't paying attention to the bounds of the `ListView` itself. I'm pretty sure that I've run into other drag-and-drop `ListView` implementations, but I don't remember any names, and I have no idea if they'd suffer from the same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I used an older implementation of TouchListView.

Had to update the following line in

```
private void startDragging(Bitmap bm, int x, int y) {
```

from

```
mWindowParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
```

to

```
mWindowParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT;
```

That's it :-)